# Javascript - Detect a click on the x-webkit-speech icon

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

I'm using the x-webkit-speech attribute on an input element. When the microphone icon is clicked I'd like to fire a Javascript function but can't seem to figure out a way to detect the click. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I've figured out, the [W3C Speech Input API Specification (Draft)](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html) does specify an [onspeechstart](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html#event-speech-start) and on [onspeechend](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html#event-speech-end) however at time of writing Chrome hasn't yet implemented these as onwebkitspeechstart and onwebkitspeechend.

So my work around is creating two input elements one uses x-webkit-speech but has a small width so its only displaying the microphone icon. The other input doesn't have x-webkit-speech. This allows me to detect the onclick event on the x-webkit-speech input and when the webkitspeechchange event is fired I move the text to the larger input.

Also there's a little trick I found, you can scale the microphone size:

```
  #theinput {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3.0, 3.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(3.0, 3.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(3.0, 3.0);
    transform: scale(3.0, 3.0);
  }
```

Comment: Reducing the size of the input overrides the left padding (used for the icon) on my Ubuntu Chromium. So the input value is going over the icon.

Comment: The non-`-webkit` prefixes are useless, in this case, since the microphone is only visible in Chrome.

Comment: Very true, can't really remember writing this, maybe I was future proofing but seems a little bit of overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible at this moment, and probably never will.

This is an experimental control and the rendering is done by the browser itself. Its impossible to customize or bind action to events on the mic icon at this point.

Also relying on something that just few people will have support is just good for an specific experiment.

You can leave suggestions on http://www.webkit.org/, but we should wait for a HTML5 standard to get all the power of it.

Regards

Comment: I'm writing a Chrome extension so all my users will have access to this functionality. I'm starting to think I just need to overlay something over the mic to catch the click but I haven't tested it yet.